# PHPUnit filenaming conventions

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm just starting to try out phpunit on some existing code. The naming convention we use is that the MyClass class should be in MyClass.class.php. PHPUnit seems to require that the file should be called MyClass.php.

Is there any way around this?

I noticed it while trying to generate a skeleton test class:

```
phpunit --skeleton-test MyClass.class

PHPUnit 3.3.4 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Could not find class "MyClass.class" in "/home/jd/skeleton/classes/MyClass.class.php".
Fatal error: Call to a member function getOutClassName() on a non-object in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php on line 470
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its not a requirement, its just assumptive. You can write your own test-cases.

Skeleton just makes a mock-up one "the easy way" that makes dummy functions for all your classes dummy functions.

Also,

```
phpunit --skeleton-test MyClass  MyClass.class.php
```

Might do what you want.

```
   Usage: phpunit [switches] UnitTest [UnitTest.php]
       phpunit [switches] <directory>

--skeleton-class         Generate Unit class for UnitTest in UnitTest.php.
--skeleton-test          Generate UnitTest class for Unit in Unit.php.
```

so by that reasoning, if you don't tell it what file the class is in it will try guess, if you do tell it what file the class is in, it wont guess.

Answer (score 0):

I ran up against a similar problem when the class a skeleton is being generated for is namespaced. I'm using phpunit 3.5.6 from the command-line. The phpUnit documentation example didn't work for me and I couldn't find the answer online so I figured I share it here. Suppose you have class Foo inside directory /my/dir and it's declared in a single file Foo.php so the full path to the class file is /my/dir/Foo.php

Also suppose that Foo is declared as follows:

```
<?php

namespace my\space;
class Foo
{
    ...
}
```

In order to generate a test skeleton I made sure I was in the directory where Foo.php resides and then I ran the following command:

```
user[/my/dir]$ phpunit --skeleton-test my\\dir\\Foo Foo.php
```

That got my skeleton to generate. The key was escaping the backslash as the documentation of phpUnit mentions namespaces but only shows one backslash. Hope this helps someone.